# Apply string replacements on array and remove unaffected elements

Tags: php, arrays, replace, filtering, prefix

Is it possible to do something like this with an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => event_foo
    [1] => event_bar
    [2] => 
)

array_filter($array, str_replace("event_", ""));
```

so that I can end up with an array only containing values with their "event_" prefix removed?

Desired result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => bar
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not directly use `str_replace` on the orginal array itself.

how about this code :

```
$arr = ["event_foo","event_bar",""];
print_r(array_filter((str_replace("event_","",$arr))));
```

Comment: Dang, I completely overlooked that `str_replace` takes arrays. You should also work in `array_filter` to make this a complete answer.

Comment: well I forgot that the op also wanted to remove the null values, silly of me :P , so here is the updated answer, hope it gets accepted

Answer (score 0):

Not in one go unless you unroll it into a `foreach` loop, but you can `map` over the result of a `filter`:

```
array_map(function ($s) { return str_replace('event_', '', $s); },
          array_filter($array))
```

Comment: Thanks, but that only partially works. Empty values are removed, but prefix 'event_' still remains.

Answer (score 0):

```
$PREFIX = 'event_';

$array = array('event_foo' => 3, 'event_bar' => 7);

$prefixLength = strlen($PREFIX);

foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
  if (substr($key, 0, $prefixLength) === $PREFIX)
  {
    $newKey = substr($key, $prefixLength);
    $array[$newKey] = $value;
    unset($array[$key]);
  }
}

print_r($array); // shows: Array ( [foo] => 3 [bar] => 7 )
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a native function that is concise and perfectly suited to handle your replace&filter task.

`preg_filter()` will attempt to replace all strings as described in the pattern and the replacement string, then it will only return the strings which were successfully modified.

`^` in the pattern is a metacharacter that means the start of the string -- this ensures that the pattern can only match `event_` if it is found at the start of the string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/qajS64))

```
$array = [
    'event_foo',
    'event_bar',
    '',
];

var_export(
    preg_filter('/^event_/', '', $array)
);
```